# How to map array of objects with components and pass props these components?

Tags: reactjs

I have many icon components with the same structure:

```
const DeliveryIcon: React.FC<IFavoriteIconProps> = ({ width = 20, height = 20, filled = false, fill = '#222222' }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      height={width}
      width={height}
      viewBox="0 0 48 48"
      fill={filled ? '#f44336' : fill}
    >
      <path d="..." />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Then in some component I made an array of objects which I'd like to render:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Delivery',
    icon: <DeliveryIcon fill={'#6bc553b0'} width={28} height={28} />,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Prices',
    icon: <Price fill={'#6bc553b0'} width={28} height={28} />,
  },
];

const InfoBlock: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className={classes['info-block']}>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div className={classes['info-block-item']} key={item.id}>
          {item.icon}
          {item.name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I pass prop `fill, width and height` to icon component in map render function instead of repeating it in array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best that I can think of is:

```js
const iconProps = {
  fill: '#6bc553b0',
  width: 28,
  height: 28
}
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Delivery',
    icon: <DeliveryIcon {...iconProps} />,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Prices',
    icon: <Price {...iconProps} />,
  },
];
```

The `data` array unfortunately isn't just plain objects but includes JSX so we can't later modify the icons themselves in `array.map()` because the icon components have already been instantiated by this time. I am not sure if instantiated is the right word for this but once we write JSX, we have basically called `React.createElement()` and can no longer pass props.

Answer (score 3):

Just giving another option, without the icon object being instantiated on the data array.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Delivery',
    Icon: DeliveryIcon
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Prices',
    Icon: Price
  },
];

const InfoBlock: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className={classes['info-block']}>
      {data.map(({id, name, Icon}) => (
        <div className={classes['info-block-item']} key={id}>
          <Icon fill={'#6bc553b0'} width={28} height={28} />
          {name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: JXS component's name must start with an uppercase first letter so `<item.icon />` should be `<Item.Icon />`, same in the above data array, key should be `Icon` insted of `icon`. Otherwise a good solution!

Comment: You could use the key name `icon` and rename it `Icon` in your destructuration, it would be cleaner imo.